# How can I ssh into my meteor app?

Tags: node.js, ssh, ffmpeg, meteor

I am working on a meteor project, and I deployed it at meteor.com, I used ffmpeg library for some audio option, so I need to install ffmpeg on meteor server.

I successfully executed following command to install ffmpeg on meteor server.

1]. git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git

2]. cd FFmpeg && ./configure --disable-yasm

3]. cd FFmpeg && make

but in 4th command I am facing an issue

4]. cd FFmpeg && make install
then I am getting errror like:-

```
      cannot create directory /usr/local/man/man1 :permission denied
```

and when I used cd FFmpeg && sudo make install      then getting error:-

```
    sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

so what should I do to solve this error or can install ffmpeg library

thanks..

Comment: Can you set any options on the call to `configure` to set the install directory, or maybe tell it to not include the manuals?  It looks like you don't have root access in your shell, and hence do not have permissions to write the required manual files to /usr/local/man.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The error is in the make file.  It's trying to add manuals to the specified folder.  These are used with the `man` command in *nix systems.  Usually the `configure` scripts (called in step 2 above) have a TON of options you can pass in, in fact you are passing in one with `--disable-yasm`.  Since you apparently do not have root access to install this, I am suggesting you investigate the options of the `configure` script to see if maybe you can disable the man pages or install them in an alternate location, one in which you would have write access.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get access via ssh to apps on meteor.com & I don't think allow you to use custom binaries on their infrastructure.

Each instance is in a sort of vm which doesn't give you root access so you can't make any binaries.

If you want to use ffmpeg/custom binaries with your app you would have to use your own infrastructure like on heroku (which is also free), AWS or digitalocean.

The Dev-Ops that `meteor deploy` affords is a deployment of the bundled meteor app only. There is no other access (ftp, ssh, or otherwise) given besides the mongo database (via `meteor mongo <siteurl>`